# how to merge data array of to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

**how to merge data array of to array in php?**

i have 2 arrays like:

```
$a=[1,2]; $b =[3,4];
```

and i want to merge data like:

```
$data = [[1,3]],[2,4]];
```

how to code in php like array_merge or something in php or laravel?

i have try using array_merge but not my expectation data like this:

```
$data = array_merge($a, $b);
```

but data always return

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

i have clue about this, can someone help this problem?

Comment: you want each single converted to json ?

Comment: `[{1,3},{2,4}]` is neither valid PHP or JSON. If you just want to add both arrays as sub-arrays: `$data = [$a, $b];`.

Comment: i want data like php array object

Comment: _"i want data like php array object"_ - You need to explain further. I have no idea what you mean by "php array object".

Comment: data like this [{1,3},{2,4}]

Comment: Then you need to manually create it as a string. As I've already mentioned, `[{1,3},{2,4}]` is not a valid format in PHP (or JS/JSON). `$data = [{1,3},{2,4}];` will throw a syntax error. PHP doesn't have functions for automatically create random custom formats. And `{ }` is JSON syntax for objects, but they need to be  `{"key": value}`. Without the key, it will just be an array (using `[ ]`)

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? What are you going to do with the results? I don't know of any format where that syntax would make sense, tbh.

Comment: im sorry @M.Eriksson i mean data like [[1,3],[2,4]]

Comment: if you want php array of objects then you can do like this `$a=[1,2]; $b =[3,4];
       $data=[(object)$a,(object)$b];`

Comment: @Moshiur - We've already concluded that it won't give the OP what they ask for in the question (demo: https://3v4l.org/8ZWRS), and if you check the last comment from the OP, they say that they actually mean arrays, not objects. They also want to change the order of the values. From `[1,2]` to `[1,3]` etc.

Comment: @Ade using array_combine and after that manually set data as per requirement. share the example here 
`$data=[1,2];
$value=['a','b'];
$result = array_combine($data,$value);
print_r($result);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we concluded in the comments that you actually want a multidimensional array, we need to create new arrays so we can swap the values around between the original arrays.

Here's one possible solution (the comments explain the different parts)

```php
$a = [1,2];
$b = [3,4];

// Initiate a new array
$newArray = [];

// Iterate through one of the arrays
foreach ($a as $index => $value) {
    // On each iteration, take the values from both arrays for that specific array index
    // and add them as a new sub array.
    $newArray[] = [
        $a[$index],
        $b[$index]
    ];
}
```

`$newArray` will now contain a multidimensional array:

```
[[1,3],[2,4]]
```

Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/okHhQ